# How to download TIGER data (for Postgis_tiger_geocoder) for one state through FileZila

Tags: postgis, geocoding, tiger, ftp

I'm having issues to download  Tiger data from the census site using the PostGIS packaged postgis_tiger_geocoder loader scripts. I want to try it using FileZila.

```
FTP site: ftp2.census.gov
USER:  anonymous
PASSWORD:  anonymous
```

Once I'm on the folder of interest:

```
/geo/tiger/TIGER2016/
```

There are a lot of folders from which I have to download files:
Which files do I need to download for the postgis_tiger_geocoder to work

[image]

How can I handle to download the files for one state from here?

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic.  the user is asking what specific files he needs to get for the geocoding to work with the postgis packaged postgis tiger geocoder.  I rephrased a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

You need files from state, county - there should just be one in each folder for these since these are for the whole country.

For each state you need files from below folders, all the ones prefixed with the code of your state.  The state code is the statefp field listed in the state table.

addr, county, cousub, edges, faces, featnames, place, state

So for example for massachusetts (statefp = '25')  - so in addr you'd need all files starting with tl_2016_25*.zip

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the /geo/tiger/TIGER2016 folder from where you've connected to the root

You can navigate the themes of data you're after.

You can find more info here:

https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html